# Multiple consecutive join operations on PySpark

Tags: performance, apache-spark, join, pyspark, partitioning

I am running a PySpark application where we are comparing two large datasets of 3GB each. There are some differences in the datasets, which we are filtering via outer join.

```py
mismatch_ids_row = (sourceonedf.join(sourcetwodf, on=primary_key,how='outer').where(condition).select(primary_key)
mismatch_ids_row.count()
```

So the output of join on count is a small data of say 10 records. The shuffle partition at this point is about 30 which has been counted as amount of data/partition size(100Mb).

After the result of the join, the previous two datasets are joined with the resultant joined datasets to filter out data for each dataframe.

```py
df_1 = sourceonedf.join(mismatch_ids_row, on=primary_key, how='inner').dropDuplicates()
df_2 = sourcetwodf.join(mismatch_ids_row, on=primary_key, how='inner').dropDuplicates()
```

Here we are dropping duplicates since the result of first join will be double via outer join where some values are null.

These two dataframes are further joined to find the column level comparison and getting the exact issue where the data is mismatched.

```py
df = (df_1.join(df_2,on=some condition, how="full_outer"))
result_df = df.count()
```

The resultant dataset is then used to display as:

```py
result_df.show()
```

The issue is that, the first join with more data is using merge sort join with partition size as 30 which is fine since the dataset is somewhat large.

After the result of the first join has been done, the mismatched rows are only 10 and when joining with 3Gb is a costly operation and using broadcast didn't help.
The major issue in my opinion comes when joining two small resultant datasets in second join to produce the result. Here too many shuffle partitions are killing the performance.

The application is running in client mode as spark run for testing purposes and the parameters are sufficient for it to be running on the driver node.

Here is the DAG for the last operation:

[image]

As an example:

```
data1 = [(335008138387,83165192,"yellow","2017-03-03",225,46),
                (335008138384,83165189,"yellow","2017-03-03",220,4),
                (335008138385,83165193,"yellow","2017-03-03",210,11),
                (335008138386,83165194,"yellow","2017-03-03",230,12),
                (335008138387,83165195,"yellow","2017-03-03",240,13),
                (335008138388,83165196,"yellow","2017-03-03",250,14)
                  ]

    data2 = [(335008138387,83165192,"yellow","2017-03-03",300,46),
                (335008138384,83165189,"yellow","2017-03-03",220,10),
                (335008138385,83165193,"yellow","2017-03-03",210,11),
                (335008138386,83165194,"yellow","2017-03-03",230,12),
                (335008138387,83165195,"yellow","2017-03-03",240,13),
                (335008138388,83165196,"yellow","2017-03-03",250,14)
                  ]
    
    field = [
            StructField("row_num",LongType(),True),
             StructField("tripid",IntegerType(),True), 
             StructField("car_type",StringType(),True),
             StructField("dates", StringType(), True),
             StructField("pickup_location_id", IntegerType(), True),
             StructField("trips", IntegerType(), True)
            ]

    schema = StructType(field)

    sourceonedf = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1,schema=schema)
    sourcetwodf = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
```

They have just two differences, on a larger dataset think of these as 10 or more differences.
df_1 will get rows from 1st sourceonedf based on mismatch_ids_row and so will the df_2. They are then joined to create another resultant dataframe which outputs the data.

How can we optimize this piece of code so that optimum partitions are there for it to perform faster that it does now.

At this point it takes ~500 secs to do whole activity, when it can take about 200 secs lesser and why does the show() takes time as well, there are only 10 records so it should print pretty fast if all are in 1 partition I guess.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is `primary_key` an actual column? or an expression? I mean, is it `sourceonedf.col1== sourcetwodf.col1` or `'col1'` or `['col1', 'col2']` ?

Comment: Are both `primary_key` the same in the first line?

Comment: `on=some condition` on the last join is different than `on=primary_key` on the first join?

Comment: yes, primary key is same for both sets and is a column, and some condition is different on last join

Comment: In the example, what conditions would represent `primary_key`, `condition` and `some condition`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go without `df_1` and `df_2`. After the first 'outer' join you have all the data in that table already.

Cache the result of the first join (as you said, the dataframe is small):

```py
# (Removed the select after the first join)
mismatch_ids_row = sourceonedf.join(sourcetwodf, on=primary_key, how='outer').where(condition)
mismatch_ids_row.cache()
mismatch_ids_row.count()
```

Then you should be able to create a **self-join** condition. When joining, use dataframe aliases for explicit control:

```py
result_df = (
    mismatch_ids_row.alias('a')
    .join(mismatch_ids_row.alias('b'), on=some condition...)
    .select(...)
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure id `.cache()` would work without `.count()`. I think cache is a good practice, because later you access that dataframe at least 2 times and since it's small, it should be fast to read from the cache.

Comment: You are saying don't use ```df_1 = sourceonedf.join(mismatch_ids_row, on=primary_key, how='inner').dropDuplicates()
df_2 = sourcetwodf.join(mismatch_ids_row, on=primary_key, how='inner').dropDuplicates()```  but then how will I get the rows from each of the original dataset which has mismatches?

Comment: Without any sample, it's hard to say, but in theory - your mismatches are already inside `mismatch_ids_row`. Or is there any other record that needs to be collected from `sourceonedf` and `sourcetwodf`? When creating `df_1` and`df_2` you use the same join condition, so I can't see what other records are being collected using the inner joins.

Comment: The schema, datatypes, keys are all same. Need to compare two dataframes which can result into what diffferences are there between datasets. Which key has a row which has mismatches. So, mismatches are there in mismatch_ids_row. Yeah same records are being collected on joins of the same keys.

Comment: It would be simpler if you could prepare small example dataframes. By doing this, quite often we find problems ourselves. And if not, then for others it's a lot simpler. I still can't see point in having df_1 and df_2. Example inputs could help.

Comment: Please see example on the question.